# Error executing script TestApp: ApplicationContext requested, but is not present in the build binding

Tags: grails, groovy, selenium, grails-plugin

In `_Events.groovy`, I created a test type as such:

```
//setup selenium test type
eventAllTestsStart = {
    phasesToRun << "selenium"
}
def seleniumTestType = new JUnit4GrailsTestType('selenium', 'selenium', new GrailsTestMode(autowire: true))
seleniumTests = [seleniumTestType]
seleniumTestPhasePreparation = {
}
seleniumTestPhaseCleanUp = {
}
```

When I run:

`grails test-app selenium:`, I get this:

```
Error executing script TestApp: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationContext
requested, but is not present in the build binding
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that autowire line? Looks suspicious, ehh? Remove it.

```
//setup selenium test type
def seleniumTestType = new JUnit4GrailsTestType('selenium', 'selenium')
seleniumTests = [seleniumTestType]
seleniumTestPhasePreparation = {
    unitTestPhasePreparation()
}
seleniumTestPhaseCleanUp = {
    unitTestPhaseCleanUp()
}

eventAllTestsStart = {
    phasesToRun << "selenium"
}
```